# Devise, IE8 and Authentication prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I've been using Devise in an app for a while and it all works fine for me in all browsers (Safari, Firefox, IE6, 7, 8 etc)

I have a new user who has a fairly locked down version of IE8 and as soon as they try to access the app, before they even get to the login page, they get a Windows Authentication prompt appear.  If they try to enter the login details they have been provided it fails.  I'm not really worried about it failing, as the authentication prompt shouldn't be appearing.

I've tried suggesting allowing cookies etc, but they are still getting the problem.  Has anyone got any suggestions as to other things we could look at?

Comment: Any chance that the authentication is for their local proxy/firewall rather than your application?

Comment: It may well be. I'm no networking guy though, so don't know what to suggest.  I'll get them to try the site in Firefox or Safari and we'll see what happens.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Do you know what security options are set in the IE8 version of your user? It would be a good idea to be able to repeat the bug on your machine, and then find out which IE8 option causes the problem with devise.

Comment: It's a typical corporate lock down.  The IT guy I've spoken to isn't that aware of what security options are set.  I'm just trying different settings, but I can't replicate. I think the proxy/firewall may be a good place to start.

Comment: They've tried it in Firefox and it all works fine, so I'm guessing the proxy/firewall issue is now out of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the upgrading to Rails 3.0.5 and Devise 1.2 resolves this problem